# CUDA block clustering: size, dimensions and divisibility restrictions

Tags: cuda, nvidia

Beginning with the Hopper u-architecture, NVIDIA GPUs support [block clustering](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#thread-block-clusters) (CUDA programming guide §2.2.1). The description there leaves me with two conundra (conundrums?)

1. The guide says that

   > a maximum of 8 thread blocks in a cluster is supported as a portable cluster size in CUDA

   but the H100 white paper [says](https://nvdam.widen.net/s/5bx55xfnxf/gtc22-whitepaper-hopper) that it supports clusters of 16 blocks. Do these statements contradict, or is 16 just "not portable" somehow (as though any of these hardware limits is "portable"...?)
2. There's no indication regarding how one may arrange the 8 or 16 blocks into axes. Will any combination of dimensions be accepted, provided that its volume is less than the maximum? Does the first dimension need to be the largest? What about sizes which don't divide 8 or 16? e.g. 2 x 3 x 1 ?
3. Must the cluster dimensions divide the grid dimensions in every axis (x, y, and z)? Overall?

Answer (score 3):

> Do these statements contradict

No I don't believe they contradict.  For devices that support clustering, presumably now and in the future (sm_90, i.e. "hopper" is the only example at the moment), my read of [that paragraph](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-block-clusters) is that there will be a minimum cluster size of 8 supported *architecturally* (but see note below).  This is being referred to as a "portable" size, where "portable" means "works on any *architecture* that supports clustering".  However an allowance is made for per-device-architecture examples to exceed that "limit", and the suggestion is also given to query the appropriate limit for the device you are running on, if desired.  If you did that on hopper, you should receive a numerical value of 16.  Note: there is still an allowance made for e.g. MIG slices, with an indication that the cluster size may be reduced.  Therefore the recommended practice is to query the cluster size supported as indicated:

> Identification of these smaller configurations, as well as of larger configurations supporting a thread block cluster size beyond 8, is architecture-specific and can be queried using the `cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialClusterSize` API.

If, after consuming all that, you feel there is a contradiction, I'm not going to argue the point.  However the necessary instructions have been given for programming safety and correctness.

> There's no indication regarding how one may arrange the 8 or 16 blocks into axes.

Correct, and it seems to me that there are no limits.  Similar to threadblock dimensions where the individual axes can take on a range of values, but the product cannot exceed a limit (1024), we seem to have a [similar](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-block-clusters) arrangement here (the similarity to threadblock dimensions is called out in the documentation).  There appear to be [no particular per-axis limits](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cluster-size-limitation/279795/5), so long as the product does not exceed the maximum.  An exhaustive test could easily be attempted, if desired.

> Must the cluster dimensions divide the grid dimensions in every axis (x, y, and z)? Overall?

Yes, the grid dimension is expected to be a multiple of the cluster dimension.  Including for each dimension.  This is [mentioned](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-block-clusters) in the code example comments:

> // The grid dimension must be a multiple of cluster size.

Comment: " An exhaustive test could easily be attempted, if desired." <- If one has a Hopper accessible, which I currently don't. We'll probably get one at work sometime this year, but I'm working on updating my API wrappers now, so I have to make decisions.